# Reordering each row of a datatable

Tags: r, sorting, data.table

I am searching a way to reorder each row of a data.table in alphatical order in an efficient way. So I assume that each column does give the same information and is comparable. When you see the example it will make more sense:

```
test <- data.table(A = c("A", "b", "c"), 
                   B = c(1,"a","d"), 
                   C = c("F", 0, 1))
```

Expected result:

```
result <- data.table(t(apply(test,1, sort))) 
names(result) <- colnames(test)
```

In this solution I have to loop through all the rows, can this be prevented?
For 2 columns I found a efficient way to solve this problem:

```
result <- data.table(A = pmin(test$A, test$B), B = pmax(test$A, test$B) )
```

But this solution does not work well for more than 2 columns

EDIT:

Lets add a benchmark of the different solutions on two columns:

```
test <- data.table(A = sample(c("A","B", "C", "D"), 1000000, replace = T),
                   B =  sample(c("A","B", "C", "D"), 1000000, replace = T))
OptionOne <- function(test){
  result <- data.table(A = pmin(test$A, test$B), B = pmax(test$A, test$B) )
}

OptionTwo <- function(test){
  test[, names(test) := as.list(sort(unlist(.SD))), 1:nrow(test)][]
}
OptionThree <- function(test){
  test[, id := .I]
  test <- melt(test, id.vars = "id")
  setorder(test, id, value) 
  test[, variable1 := seq_len(.N), by = id]
  dcast(test, id ~ variable1, value.var = "value")
}

system.time(OptionOne(test))
#user  system elapsed 
#0.13    0.00    0.12
system.time(OptionTwo(test))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  17.58    0.00   18.27
system.time(OptionThree(test))
#user  system elapsed 
# 0.23    0.00    0.24
```

It seems like for two columns the pmin and pmax is the most efficient way but for more columns the reshape does a good job.

Comment: Sorting strings combined with integers doesn't make sense to me and is dangerous. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Maybe the example is wrong in real they are all characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data.table is conceptionally in the wrong shape. Sorting over rows (i.e., over variables) does not make sense. Thus, to do this efficiently you need to reshape:

```
library(data.table)
test <- data.table(A = c("A", "b", "c"), 
                   B = c(1,"a","d"), 
                   C = c("F", 0, 1))
test[, id := .I]

test <- melt(test, id.vars = "id")
setorder(test, id, value) 
#   id variable value
#1:  1        B     1
#2:  1        A     A
#3:  1        C     F
#4:  2        C     0
#5:  2        B     a
#6:  2        A     b
#7:  3        C     1
#8:  3        A     c
#9:  3        B     d
```

If you must, you can then reshape again, though I would not recommend that.

```
test[, variable1 := seq_len(.N), by = id]

dcast(test, id ~ variable1, value.var = "value")
#   id 1 2 3
#1:  1 1 A F
#2:  2 0 a b
#3:  3 1 c d
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try

```
test[, names(test) := as.list(sort(unlist(.SD))), 1:nrow(test)][]
```

Comment: This method really costs a lot of time if I compare the 2 columns method with pmin and pmax with this method than the pmin and pmax is much faster.